# Изменяемый словарь в Python

Tags: python, словарь

Всё никак не могу сделать изменяемый словарь в питоне. Пытаюсь сделать словарь вида "ник_человека : его_айди_ВК", да так, чтобы я мог из своего бота ВК добавлять туда людей, и они сохранялись. Пока что додумался лишь до такого:

```
def addPlayerToList(idp,nick):
playerDict[nick] = idp
playerDict[idp] = nick
np.save('playersdict.npy', playerDict)
read_dictionary = np.load('playersdict.npy', allow_pickle='TRUE').item()
```

Но он заменяет прошлого добавленного человека. Как же можно сделать изменяемый словарь в питоне?
Сам словарь:

```
playerDict = {'айди' : 'ник'}
```

Comment: Если ники разные, то не должен заменять

Comment: Добавьте сюда кусок кода, пожалуйста, ещё с объявлением словаря и вызовом функции, если мой ответ ниже не поможет.

Comment: Зачем вы сперва записываете файл, а затем читаете его обратно? Логичнее было бы прочитать файл, внести изменения в словарь, записать файл.

Comment: Так как с помощью бота я и читаю из словаря ники, и открываю уже новый, измененный словарь

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, вы делаете правильно. Затираться не должно. Вот упрощённый пример ниже.
Не совсем понятно, зачем вам нужно: `playerDict[idp] = nick`, но вряд ли дело в этом.
Сравните со своим кодом, найдите в чем различие.

```
def addPlayerToList(idp,nick):
    playerDict[nick] = idp

playerDict = {}    
print (playerDict) # печатает: {}
nick = 'Вася'
idp = '1'
addPlayerToList (idp,nick)
print (playerDict) # печатает: {'Вася': '1'} 
nick = 'Петя'
idp = '2'
addPlayerToList (idp,nick)
print (playerDict) # печатает: {'Вася': '1', 'Петя': '2'}
```

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось:-) P.s. Я уж было решил, что в словарях что-то не понимаю, так что все проверил выше.

Comment: При перезапуске кода этот словарь исчезнет, в этом и проблема. Мне нужно создать изменяемый и сохраняемый словарь. playerDict[idp] = nick нужен для обратного - по айди определить ник

Comment: Это неправильно. Надо просто брать ключ по значению. Что если кто-то придумает себе ник, совпадающий с чьим-нибедь айди?

Comment: То он проследует на три весёлые буквы :)
Ники и айди у всех разные, просто не могут быть одинаковыми. Да и речь идёт о 50-100 позициях, которые я сам ручками добавляю

Comment: @szarkan, я просто убрал из кода всякие сохранения словаря, так как `np` у меня не установлен. Но у вас же вопрос был: "как сделать изменяемый словарь?" Просто сохраняйте словарь перед выходом из кода или, если не определить выход - то после каждого добавления (так похуже). И считывайте словарь при входе либо в крайнем случае перед записью туда. У вас что проблема с тем, как считывать и как сохранять словарь? Тогда вопрос вообще не в словаре.

Answer (score 0):

Костыльно, убого, но я как бы не сеньор, поэтому можно

```
def addPlayerToList(idp,nick):
    read_dictionary = np.load('playersdict.npy', allow_pickle='TRUE').item()
    # загружает файлик с словарем и записывает его в переменную
    read_dictionary[nick] = idp
    # добавляет ей знаечение
    np.save('playersdict.npy', read_dictionary)
    # сохраняет в этот же файлик уже изменённый словарь
    read_dictionary = np.load('playersdict.npy', allow_pickle='TRUE').item()
    # открывает уже новый чтобы читать
```